# Lattice vectors and modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers, integer-lattices

Consider a set of positive integers $q,p_1,\dots,p_n$, all greater than 1 and having no common factors.  Let $x$ be the vector $(p_1,\dots,p_n)^T\in\mathbb{Z}^n$.  Define a lattice $$L:= \left\{a_0 x + q\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\hat{e}_k \: : a_k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$$ where $\hat{e}_i$ is a standard basis vector for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> **Question:** Is there a way to find the primitive basis vectors of this lattice?

Example: for $(q,p_1,p_2)=(55,13,31)$ the basis vectors are $v=(-5,5)$ and $v=(7,4)$ as shown below.

[image: Lattice]

I have been able to work it out only by brute force and am struggling to see the pattern.

The only thing I have been able to calculate directly is that the matrix $M$ whose rows are the primitive basis vectors $v$ should have determinant $|M|=q^{n-1}$.

Comment: Possibly related to Halton sequences?

Comment: The primitive basis vectors are the $n$ linearly independent vectors which relate the nearest $n$ other lattice points. Where nearest here means those in neighbouring Wigner–Seitz cells. I believe these are the usual definitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75032/discussion-between-yly-and-comptonscattering).